# How to report large number of p.values in a table?

Tags: reporting, tables

I have been comparing 13 groups to one another to assess significant differences. The simplest method of writing this up was a table, and there are numerous significant and non-significant results, which are highlighted appropriately.

In the results section of my paper, I have written "(as summarised in table II and table III)." Because there is no particular set pattern and a lot of random results, would I be expected to elaborate on this in this section? I have other things which I can detail in my results, such as Mann-Whitney and T-Test results, so it is not empty.

Should I try and find something, and continue my results section with "Notably, sig. differences were found between....." etc., or shall I leave it as it is?

Many thanks.

Comment: I hope you're adjusting for multiple comparisons!

Comment: In addition to the really essential points made by @Peter Flom and ssdecontrol, this sounds exactly the kind of situation where a graph would show much more, with less irrelevant or dubious detail. As a journal reviewer I would urge changing any such presentation as a high priority. (As a journal editor, I would tend to agree.)

Comment: ssdecobtrol - I have adjusted my P.Value (Bonferroni correction) as I am comparing such a large number of groups to eachother - is this the correct correction to have done?

Nick Cox - thanks for commenting. Would you prefer NOT to see all P Values in a table, even though we are comparing them all to each other? Do you think a graph with asterisks when significant would be more appropriate? My supervisor has OK'd my table - but he is not a statistician. Thanks both very much.

Comment: If you think there is a better test to compare such a large number of groups to eachother, I'd really appreciate knowing it. It is now very clear than over 100 tests on the same data is very flawed, so I will look at other options.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean by "a lot of random results".  If you did many comparisons and did not correct for this, then, if the null hypotheses were all true, you would expect that 5% of the results would be significant at p < 0.05.

In general, you should comment on results that are either significant or otherwise interesting.  It could be that a nonsignificant result is very interesting.

If there is no good way to interpret your results - that is, if they don't make substantive sense - then it is a sign that something is wrong, either in what procedure you used or in your data or in your theory.